# How to extract JAVA object attribute into an 1 dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

In JAVA, how can I get a 1 dimensional array of pogNumber based on the this arrayList?

```
List<PogProdData> list = new ArrayList<PogProdData>() {
    {
        add(new PogProdData(){{setPogNumber(pogNum);setSetDate(setDate);setDpci("000000003");setPogProductData1(PogProdData1);setPogProductData2(PogProdData2););}});
        add(new PogProdData(){{setPogNumber(pogNum);setSetDate(setDate);setDpci("000000004");setPogProductData1(PogProdData1);setPogProductData2(PogProdData2););}});
        add(new PogProdData(){{setPogNumber(pogNum);setSetDate(setDate);setDpci("000001000");setPogProductData1(PogProdData1);setPogProductData2(PogProdData2););}});
        add(new PogProdData(){{setPogNumber(pogNum);setSetDate(setDate);setDpci("000005555");setPogProductData1(PogProdData1);setPogProductData2(PogProdData2););}});
        add(new PogProdData(){{setPogNumber(pogNum);setSetDate(setDate);setDpci("000006666");setPogProductData1(PogProdData1);setPogProductData2(PogProdData2););}});
    }
};
```

In C#, I can use LINQ to accomplish this goal. Like this,

```
ist.Select(x => x.PogNumber).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use some thing like this , assuming `PogNumber` is `Integer`

```
List<PogProdData> list = new ArrayList<PogProdData>();
Integer[] pogNums = list.stream().map(PogProdData::getPogNumber).toArray(Integer[]::new);
```